# How do you allocate a number to items in a listview equally?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a system in c# where members are given a loan and they pay the loan monthly depending on how much they have agreed to pay per month. So if a member takes a loan of 20000 and agrees to pay 2000 per month, that is 10 months of monthly payments. The problem is: Suppose a member decides to pay say 6000 after 3 months, how do i apportion the 6000 to the scheduled months equally?

Here's what I've tried:

```
      foreach (ListViewItem li in lstSchedule.Items)
        {
            dynamic item2 = new ListViewItem();
            Amount += LumpPaid - MonthlyDed;
            if (Amount >= MonthlyDed)
            {
                item2.SubItems[0].Text = MonthlyDed.ToString();
                item2.ImageIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (Amount < MonthlyDed)
            {
                item2.SubItems[0].Text = Amount.ToString();
                item2.ImageIndex = 0;
            }
            lstTest2.Items.Add(item2);
        }
```

Comment: Start by changing your title from ALL CAPS.

Comment: You know the complete amount and the number of paydays so its a simple division?

Comment: Hint. Start thinking this (and programming this) without a UI thing attached to it. Do the math and the UI independent on each other or even the simplest things tend to get needlessly complex.

Comment: Schedules Balance MonthlyDed EmpNo LoanID Month Year Paid
2023-07-24 40000.00 5000.00 2015N00018 L0008 7 2023 1
2023-08-24 35000.00 5000.00 2015N00018 L0008 8 2023 0
2023-09-24 30000.00 5000.00 2015N00018 L0008 9 2023 0
so if the member decides to pay say 15000 on 2023-08-24 after paying 2023-07-24, the system should be able to apportion the 15000 to the rest of the items depending on that dates monthly payment. so 2023-08-24,2023-09-24,2023-10-24 will get 5000 each and the rest 0 .this should be done through a listview with a textbox to enter the 15000 and a button to do the apportioning

Comment: If that should be something helpful to further understand your question add it to the question not in a comment.